# Cannot get integer from stringstream in C++

Tags: c++

I just searching for the stream (memory stream or file stream) then I found fstream and stringstream

But, I have tried both but it always giving me wrong output when get the integer, I am using binary file for testing this (the data isn't string, the data is bunch of bytes), here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
void getinfo(char* buffer, int length)
{
    stringstream stream(ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    // write data to stream
    stream.write(buffer, length);

    // reset position
    stream.seekg(0);

    // get 4 bytes (value is OMC with null-byte at the end)
    char* format = new char[4];
    stream >> format;

    // get 4 byte (value is depending of file version)
    int ojmver = 0; 
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ojmver), sizeof ojmver);

    // get 2 byte (encryption signature 1 that used for this file)
    short encsign1 = 0; 
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&encsign1), sizeof encsign1);

    // get 2 byte (encryption signature 2 that used for this file)
    short encsign2 = 0;
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&encsign2), sizeof encsign2);

    // get 4 byte (samples count)
    int samplecount = 0; 
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&samplecount), sizeof samplecount);

    // show info

    cout << "Format\t\t\t: " << format;
    cout << "\nOJM Ver\t\t\t: " << ojmver;
    cout << "\nEnc Sign1\t\t: " << encsign1;
    cout << "\nEnc Sign1\t\t: " << encsign2;
    cout << "\nSample Count\t\t: " << samplecount;
    cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    fstream fs = fstream("D:\\o2ma100.ojm", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    fs.seekg(0, fs.end);
    int length = fs.tellg();
    fs.seekg(0, fs.beg);

    char* buffer = new char[length];
    fs.read(buffer, length);

    if (fs)
        cout << "Length: " << length << "\nSuccess to load data\n";
    else
        cout << "Failed to load data\n";

    fs.seekg(0, fs.beg);

    // get 4 bytes (value is OMC with null-byte at the end)
    char* format = new char[4];
    fs.read(format, 4);

    // get 4 byte (value is depending of file version)
    int ojmver = 0; 
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ojmver), sizeof ojmver);

    // get 2 byte (encryption signature 1 that used for this file)
    short encsign1 = 0; 
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&encsign1), sizeof encsign1);

    // get 2 byte (encryption signature 2 that used for this file)
    short encsign2 = 0;
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&encsign2), sizeof encsign2);

    // get 4 byte (samples count)
    int samplecount = 0; 
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&samplecount), sizeof samplecount);

    cout << "\nRead Data using fs:\n";

    cout << "Format\t\t\t: " << format;
    cout << "\nOJM Ver\t\t\t: " << ojmver;
    cout << "\nEnc Sign1\t\t: " << encsign1;
    cout << "\nEnc Sign1\t\t: " << encsign2;
    cout << "\nSample Count\t\t: " << samplecount;

    fs.close();

    cout << "\n\nRead Data Using stringstream:\n";
    getinfo(buffer, length);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It give me following result:

```
Length: 4231047 // -> this correct :)
Success to load data // -> this correct :)

Read Data using fs:
Format                  : M30    // -> this correct :)
OJM Ver                 : 196608 // -> this correct :)
Enc Sign1               : 16     // -> this correct :)
Enc Sign1               : 0      // -> this correct :)
Sample Count            : 300    // -> perfect :D

Read Data Using stringstream:
Format                  : M30         // -> this correct :)
OJM Ver                 : 50331648    // -> this wrong :(
Enc Sign1               : 4096        // -> this wrong :(
Enc Sign1               : 0           // -> this wrong :(
Sample Count            : 76800       // -> this wrong :(

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I was creating similar application in C#.NET, I have tested the file, and it give me correct output (using FileStream and MemoryStream in C# with .NET Framework 2.0), here the output:

```
Length: 4231047 // -> Length is correct
Success to load data

Read Data using FileStream:
Format                  : M30     // -> this correct :)
OJM Ver                 : 196608  // -> this correct :)
Enc Sign1               : 16      // -> this correct :)
Enc Sign1               : 0       // -> this correct :)
Sample Count            : 300     // -> perfect :D

Read Data Using MemoryStream:
Format                  : M30     // -> this correct :)
OJM Ver                 : 196608  // -> this correct :)
Enc Sign1               : 16      // -> this correct :)
Enc Sign1               : 0       // -> this correct :)
Sample Count            : 300     // -> perfect :D
```

I need the stream that handle the memory and file, so I need how to read data correctly with both stream...

anyone can help me? I am new in C++
Thanks :D

**EDIT**

I changed the code, Thanks to john, it worked for fstream, but it still not work for stringstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of I/O. You are doing textual I/O when as you said you should be using binary I/O.

E.g.  not

```
int ojmver = 0; 
stream >> ojmver;
```

but

```
int ojmver = 0; 
stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ojmver), sizeof ojmver);
```

Of course this might still not be right because of size issues (are you sure int is four bytes?) and because of endianess.

Comment: You're probably going to want a `reinterpret_cast<char*>` in there too.

Comment: it give me error 'Error: argument of type "int*" is incompatible with parameter of type "char" '

Comment: @ChronoCross Look carefully, I think you missed a *

Comment: @john Wow thanks, now it works, but it not work at stringstream, here the output: Length: 4231047
Success to load data

Read Data using fs:
Format                  : M30
OJM Ver                 : 196608
Enc Sign1               : 16
Enc Sign1               : 0
Sample Count            : 300

Read Data Using stringstream:
Format                  : M30
OJM Ver                 : 0
Enc Sign1               : 0
Enc Sign1               : 0
Sample Count            : 0

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: The problem is that when you write the data into the stringstream `stream << buffer;` it's going to stop writing at the first null byte. You need to use binary (again because you are writing binary data). So `stream.write(buffer, length);`. Of course you need to pass the length into your getinfo function.

Comment: @john btw I am sure the data is 4 byte (since I already analyze it in hex editor, also the fstream work fine with 4 bytes and also I already succeeded read it in C#, and it 4 bytes (because it integer lol))

Comment: @ChronoCross You are still using text input `stream >> format;` should be `stream.read(format, 4);` in your string stream version.